# Getting ranges of arbitrary strings in SQL based on sequence dictated in a separate table

Tags: sql, join

Consider the following dataset (may look weird but want to land my point that the strings are arbitrary):

**Table A**

| TicketId | StartAnimal | EndAnimal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monkey | Bee |
| 1 | Lion | Buffalo |

**Table B**

| Animal | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| Monkey | 1 |
| Zebra | 2 |
| Bee | 3 |
| Turtle | 4 |
| Lion | 5 |
| Buffalo | 6 |

Is it possible to retrieve the animals that correspond to Ticket ID 1 based on the different "ranges" in each of its rows? For example,for Ticket ID 1 the following animals should be retrieved: Monkey, Zebra, Bee, Lion, Buffalo.

As you can see the animal strings themselves have no order logic to it, but the sequence can be leveraged for it. I'm just failing to come up with how to reference it for each row in a single query.

**Edit**
As an edge case, sometimes the EndAnimal might not even have a sequence to start with, in which case only the StartAnimal should be returned. As an example, assuming Bee is not in the sequence table, we should only get Monkey, Lion and Buffalo. Is that something SQL can handle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways, one such way is to inner join the tables to find the corresponding start and end sequences and then find those rows that qualify:

```
with s as (
    select bs.Sequence s1, IsNull(be.sequence,1) s2, a.ticketId
    from a left join b bs on bs.animal = a.StartAnimal
    left join b be on be.Animal = a.EndAnimal
)
select b.Animal
from b
join s on b.Sequence >=s1 and b.Sequence <= s2
where s.ticketId = 1
order by b.Sequence;
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sPcjiqv9)

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I needed. This helped me identify an edge case however, where sometimes the EndAnimal might not even have a sequence to start with, in which case only the StartAnimal should be returned. As an example, assuming Bee is not in the sequence table, we should only get Monkey, Lion and Buffalo. Is that something SQL can handle?

Comment: @EtooN You would simply change to an outer join and handle any NULLs, I have amended above (untested as not at PC but should work).

Comment: I see the logic and it makes sense, however in your example the "1" replacement works because its retrieving the Monkey specifically. If instead we place Bee back in, but remove Buffalo, it is no longer retrieving Lion as expected, see https://dbfiddle.uk/m7pX6A86

Comment: I think I got it working as such: https://dbfiddle.uk/zpHLlk8R . Accepting your answer, thank you very much!